How to iterate over each sensor unit in ultrasonic sound field simulation using `k-Wave`'s Python implementation?
I have collected a dataset of vascular images along with vascular semantic segmentation data. Previously, based on the manually segmented images from the dataset, I completed binarization of the vessels, marking vessel pixels as 1 and non-vessel pixels as 0, represented by the variable vessel_matrix.
Next, I plan to use the Python implementation k-wave-python to simulate ultrasound signals based on vessel_matrix.
Here is my code:
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
from kwave.data import Vector
from kwave.kgrid import kWaveGrid
from kwave.kmedium import kWaveMedium
from kwave.ksensor import kSensor
from kwave.ksource import kSource
from kwave.kspaceFirstOrder2D import kspaceFirstOrder2DC
from kwave.options.simulation_execution_options import SimulationExecutionOptions
from kwave.options.simulation_options import SimulationOptions
from kwave.utils.mapgen import make_cart_circle

# Segmentation mask of the vessels. Each pixel is marked as 1 if it belongs to a vessel, and 0 otherwise
vessel_matrix: np.ndarray = ...

kgrid = kWaveGrid(
    N=Vector(list(vessel_matrix.shape)),  # Number of grid points
    spacing=Vector([1e-4, 1e-4])  # Physical size of each grid point
)
medium = kWaveMedium(sound_speed=1540,  # Sound speed in water or tissue
                     density=1000,
                     alpha_coeff=0.75,  # Absorption coefficient
                     alpha_power=1.5,  # Power index of absorption coefficient
                     BonA=6)  # Nonlinear absorption parameter in the medium

kgrid.makeTime(c=medium.sound_speed,
               t_end=(kgrid.spacing * kgrid.N * 2.2 / medium.sound_speed).max())  # 2.2 times the spatial length to ensure enough reflection paths

sensor = kSensor(mask=make_cart_circle(radius=1e-5, num_points=20))

source = kSource()
source.p0 = 1e6 * vessel_matrix


# TODO: It seems like we need to iterate over each sensor unit?

def simulate(**opts):
    simul_opts = SimulationOptions(save_to_disk=True, **opts)
    exec_opts = SimulationExecutionOptions(is_gpu_simulation=False)

    return kspaceFirstOrder2DC(kgrid=kgrid, source=source, sensor=sensor, medium=medium,
                               simulation_options=simul_opts,
                               execution_options=exec_opts)


result = simulate(pml_inside=False, data_cast='single')
print(result.keys())

# Save
file = Path('data/sensor_data.npy')
if not file.is_file():
    np.save(file, result)

print(result['p'].shape)

Reading the generated data:
import numpy as np

data: dict = np.load('data/sensor_data.npy', allow_pickle=True).item()

p: np.ndarray = data['p']
Nt = data['Nt'].item()

print(f'{Nt = }')
print(f'{p.shape = }')

Output results:
Nt = 4283
p.shape = (4283,)

Based on the collected data, it seems that I can only get the signal from the 0th sensor unit. How can this be resolved?

# TODO: It seems like we need to iterate over each sensor unit? why is this not the answer to your question?

@mkrieger1, This is my guess, but I don't know how to realize this idea.

What is the goal? To simulate a B-Mode image of the vessels? For that you would need to model the acoustic properties of the vessels, as well as a transducer source/sensor. It seems like you have defined a homogeneous medium (so there will be no reflections anywhere/at all) with an initial pressure distribution located at the vessels (idk what interpretation this might have, but probably not want you want), and a source (where you observe the waves) that is a circle (in the middle of the medium?).
